# Check if it is new address on Payment method step

Tags: magento-1.6, customer-address, billing-address

Is there any way to check via PHP, whether user selected new address in billing step?

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();
```

running above snippet provides customer adderss ID of existing address, but even after changing billing address to 'New Address' customer address ID value is not updated to NULL in quote.

Is there any other alternative to check this via PHP?

Answer (score 1):

KnowYourGento,

`Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();` is not working

Because of getCustomerAddressId() is  working whenever customer have  existing address.

Magento is `save Billing and shipping address of Quote` to `Customer` whenever `Quote` is   `finally convert to Order` at `Order review Steps` on click on Place order button.

See at  function `_prepareNewCustomerQuote(),_prepareCustomerQuote()` of class M`age_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage` copy quote address to  customer by below code:

```
Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset('checkout_onepage_quote', 'to_customer', $quote, $customer);
    $customer->setPassword($customer->decryptPassword($quote->getPasswordHash()));
    $customer->setPasswordHash($customer->hashPassword($customer->getPassword()));
    $quote->setCustomer($customer)
        ->setCustomerId(true)

;
```

**Here you have see customer id save after order to Quote**.Above function on final order place..

So, you cannot get customer address Id at `Payment step`

Comment: Thanks Amit, I agree with you that I can not get customer address id at Payment step. But the question is that in quote session "Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress()->getCustomerAddressId();" - this value gets updated only when user selects some other "existing" address from list of "existing" addresses(Dropdown). But it does not get updated to value; i.e. NULL - whenever user opts for 'New Address'.